# confluent kafka (.net) ssl configuration

Tags: .net, ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I'm trying to connect to kafka broker from .net client (Confluent.Kafka 0.9.4) via SSL, but getting AccessViolationException : *Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.* used config:

```
{
            {"group.id", kafkaGroup}, 
            {"client.id", clientId}, 
            {"bootstrap.servers", kafkaServer}, 
            {"enable.auto.commit", true},
            {"security.protocol", "ssl" },
            {"ssl.key.location", "sslkey/client.keystore.jks"},
            { "ssl.key.password", "testtest" },
            { "auto.commit.interval.ms", 5000},
            { "default.topic.config", new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    { "auto.offset.reset", "smallest" }
                }
            }

        }
```

It works fine without SSL configuration, I think there might be problem how I reference file(key) itself ? Tried resource, embedded resource and content.

Comment: Having the exact same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: @HAXEN no, just encrypted files that are sent. Confluent added this issue as bug. Maybe they'll solve it someday https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/125